# Dynamic variable in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a list of dictionaries which contains values based on another variable.

```
from random import choice, randint

male_names = [ 'Bob', 'John' ]
female_names = [ 'Alice', 'Cathrine' ]

mylist = [
    dict(
        name = choice( male_names if is_male else female_names ),
        gender = 'male' if is_male else 'female'
    )
    for _ in range(10)
    if (is_male := randint(1, 2))
]
```

As you can see in the code here, both `name` and `gender` depend on the `is_male` variable. In this example, `is_male` will eaither be 1 or 2, and not True or False. The problem is that because of the if condition, if `is_male` is False, it will simply continue with the next iteration witout doing anything. Another issue is that the if condition, makes it less readable.

Is there a way to add a variable inside the list comprehension without the if condition?
Something like this:

```
from random import choice, randint

male_names = [ 'Bob', 'John' ]
female_names = [ 'Alice', 'Cathrine' ]

mylist = [
    dict(
        name = choice( male_names if is_male == 1 else female_names ),
        gender = 'male' if is_male == 1 else 'female'
    )
    for _ in range(10)
    is_male := choice([True, False])
]
```

Comment: If you are having troubles expressing your logic in a comprehension, I suggest you use a loop instead.

Comment: Yes, in the end I think I will. I was just curious weather it's possible to do it in a comprehension. Thank you.

Comment: *Just use a for-loop*. If you are writing code like `(is_male := randint(1, 2))` just to cram things into a list comprehension that's a very good sign you shouldn't be using a list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a sequence of `is_male` values, and transform *that*:

```
mylist = [
    {
        name: choice(male_names if is_male else female_names),
        gender: 'male' if is_male else 'female'
    }
    for is_male in (choice([True, False]) for _ in range(10))
]
```